# pycharm does not connect to console with python3.8

Tags: python, console, pycharm, python-3.8

I dont know why; but since python 3.8 has been released; I cant run pycharm console and it is always in the "being connected" status.

**I have had no problem with python 3.7; since the console is opened immediately.**

Here you can see that I have tried several times to run the console but I know, even if I wait a day; It does not connect to console; but when I change the interpreter from python3.8 to python3.7, The new consoles I open are all set up within a second.

The Error:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_resolver.py:138: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if found.get(name) is not 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 33, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle.pydev_console_utils import BaseInterpreterInterface
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_thrift
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pydev_console.protocol import DebugValue, GetArrayResponse, ArrayData, ArrayHeaders, ColHeader, RowHeader, \
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_console\protocol.py", line 6, in <module>
    _console_thrift = _shaded_thriftpy.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "console.thrift"),
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\__init__.py", line 29, in load
    thrift = parse(path, module_name, include_dirs=include_dirs,
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 502, in parse
    parser.parse(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 1106, in parseopt_notrack
    p.callable(pslice)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 212, in p_struct
    val = _fill_in_struct(p[1], p[3])
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 765, in _fill_in_struct
    gen_init(cls, thrift_spec, default_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 103, in gen_init
    cls.__init__ = init_func_generator(default_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\_compat.py", line 102, in init_func_generator
    new_code = types.CodeType(len(varnames),
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

The Photo:

[image: The screen shot]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](https://img.techpowerup.org/191217/error.png))</sub>

**pycharm specs: pycharm professional version 2019.1.3**

Comment: Did you configer the interpreter? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html
Also, which python (if you installed both) is in your path?

Comment: @Swedgin; Yes I did, the configuration and the path was correctly given to the pycharm.

Comment: @Swedgin, have you any guess on what the error is saying to us ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. Been a long while since I used pycharm. Those were the only 2 problems I could think of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It works fine on *PyCharm (Community) **2019.3***.

*PyCharm* ships [[PyPI]: thriftpy](https://pypi.org/project/thriftpy) (for current version, it's a **modified** *v0.3.8*), as it needs it for different features (including the *Python Console*).

*Python 3.8* came with a set of changes (one example is [[Python]: PEP 570 -- Python Positional-Only Parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570)) requiring changes in many of the existing (3<sup>rd</sup>-party) packages in order for them to work (for some of them, there's still *WiP*).

Apparently, *ThriftPy* is one of those packages that require changes. However it hasn't been maintained since 2016, so *JetBrains* keeps (a copy / fork ?) in their repository.

Anyway, the problem you're facing, was fixed by [[GitHub]: JetBrains/intellij-community - PY-36069 Python console support for Python 3.8](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/07ef928f3b1fbc24401380110691342a558de242). 
Unfortunately, I couldn't find the issue on [JetBrains.YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com), so I don't have any additional info about it (like when it was fixed, and so on).

What I can tell you (also mentioned at the beginning), is that **it was fixed (works) in *PyCharm (Community) 2019.3***, so if you upgrade it, you should no longer have this problem.

A workaround (if upgrading is not an option) would be to apply the patch (in the commit *URL*) to your (local) *_compat.py* file. Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches (on *Win*).

Small mention: applying the reversed patch to my local file, made the problem visible.

Comment: That's great, thank you! Actually, I thought that Pycharm have probably fixed this so I updated Pycharm before setting the bounty, and it didn't solve the problem. Apparently, the update was from 1.3 to 1.4, even though version 3 was already available. Updating again solved the problem as you said.

Comment: @EllaSharakanski, thanks for the bounty and also thanks `@CristiFati` for the response.

Comment: I also have this constant issue `Connecting to console`, and I cannot use the answer's solution as I need to run PyCharm 2018.3 because that is the last version supporting 32 bit. I am using normal Python interpreter. I can run Python scripts using "Run" from the menu, but if I right-click selected lines and choose "Execute Selection in Console" (or Alt+Shift+E), there is no execution.

I added a comment to get it solved for PyCharm 2018.3 as well on https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/07ef928f3b1fbc24401380110691342a558de242

Comment: @Lorenz: You could apply the changes to your local installation, as I instructed at the end of my answer.

Comment: I found that *_combat.py* in "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\". I copied it to "C:\tmp\", then changed the code from red to green as in your commit URL https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/07ef928f3b1fbc24401380110691342a558de242. Then I renamed the ending from .py to .patch. Then I followed your link, **Patching utrunner** section, now applying it to "_combat.py" instead. I used http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm as the patch.exe instead of Cygwin patch pkg.

Comment: Now, the patch.exe does not accept the patch file: In cmd prompt, I first go to folder `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy`, I execute patch.exe with `"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\patch.exe" -i "C:\tmp\_compat.patch"` which gives me:
`patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\patch.exe: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.`

Comment: Just save https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/07ef928f3b1fbc24401380110691342a558de242/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy/_shaded_thriftpy/_compat.py locally and overwrite your version (don't forget to backup it first).

Answer (score 0):

Delete your code program and reload it from git or other svn, it would be ok for Pycharm 2021.2.3 Professional Edition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue using PyCharm 2023.2 EAP (Community Edition). Restarting Pycharm fixed it.